# How to make getline play nice with ios::exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, ifstream, eof, getline

I am trying to use an `ifstream` that I need to be able to loop through using `getline` but would like to have throw exceptions using `ios::exceptions`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );

    try {
        f.open("data/all-patents.dat", std::ifstream::in);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception opening: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    
    std::string l;
    while (!std::getline(f, l).eof()) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

But when `getline` hits EOF, it throws an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear: iostream error

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7ad8615 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Which I can confirm by catching it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );

    try {
        f.open("data/all-patents.dat", std::ifstream::in);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception opening: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    
    std::string l;
    try {
        while (!std::getline(f, l).eof()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception reading: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

}
```

Output: `Caught exception reading: basic_ios::clear: iostream error`

Why does EOF throw an exception despite me not using `ifstream::eofbit` in `ios::exceptions`'s mask? Is there a way I can keep using `ios::exceptions` without having to enclose my `while` loop in a `try`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, my understanding is that the exception mask I pass to `ios::exceptions` defines when an exception should be raised, and excluded `eofbit`.

Comment: "_The exception mask determines the error states on occurrence of which the stream throws exception of type failure._" - So, you select the states for which you'd like an exception.

Comment: Unrelated: Your loop should probably be `while (std::getline(f, l))`. I'm not sure why you have `eof()` at the end?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I test for `.eof()` to make the `while` condition false when the file reaches EOF, since `getline` returns the `ifstream` and not a `bool`.

Comment: The `ifstream` is testable in boolean contexts using [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) like I showed - which is the same as `not f.fail()` and `f.fail()` returns `true` if either `badbit` or `failbit` is true. This is usually the test you want for loops like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turn on throwing exceptions on `failbit` and later when `std::getline(f, l)` fails to extract any characters it will set `failbit` which is triggering the exception.

Comment: It turns out hitting EOF sets both `eofbit` and `failbit`. I didn't know that.

Comment: @scozy It's not hitting EOF that is setting failbit. Hitting EOF only sets `eofbit`. It's failing to extract _any_ characters that sets `failbit`. You can hit EOF and get `eofbit` set _and_ having extracted characters. In that case, `failbit` will not be set.